# taurus jmeter test fragment 'ERROR: Child Process Error: Empty results,...'

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I have been using `taurus` to run multiple test modules as a single and complete test case and all well and good. Only now I have a need to make use of test fragment to avoid duplicating codes and I ran into an issue where `taurus` keeps complaining

> ERROR: Child Process Error: Empty results,...

the same test runs in `Jmeter` as expected.

Could someone help me out, where I might missed out, please?

Here is a very simple taurus config:

test-frag-and-taurus.yml

```
execution:
- concurrency: 1
  iterations: 1
  scenario:
  script: test-frag-and-taurus.jmx
```

here jmeter looks like:

```
test plan

--thread group
----test fragment 1
------jsr223: log.info('### from fragment... ')

--thread group #disabled. also tried text fragment using include module)
----test fragment 2
------include module #point to the test fragment 1 above which saved into a separate jmx file

--thread group
----module controller
----jsr223: log.info('### from main... ')

--view result tree
```

```
2019-10-23 18:19:01,867 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler - fragment 1: ### from fragment... 
2019-10-23 18:19:01,888 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: ### from main...
```

run with taurus:

```
$ bzt test-frag-and-taurus.yml

...
18:25:45 INFO: Shutting down...
18:25:45 INFO: Post-processing...
18:25:45 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:03
18:25:45 ERROR: Child Process Error: Empty results, most likely test-frag-and-taurus.jmx (JMeterExecutor) failed. Actual reason for this can be found in logs under .../perf-test/2019-10-23_18-25-40.748202
18:25:45 ERROR: JMeter STDOUT:
Created the tree successfully using .../perf-test/modified_test-frag-and-taurus.jmx
Starting the test @ Wed Oct 23 18:25:44 BST 2019 (1571851544293)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Tidying up ... @ Wed Oct 23 18:25:44 BST 2019 (1571851544774)
... end of run
18:25:45 ERROR: JMeter log:
2019-10-23 18:25:43,948 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2019-10-23 18:25:43,969 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
...
```

Answer (score 1):

just noticed the following line in the log which i left out from the taurus log included above...

```
2019-10-24 16:25:58,226 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: No enabled thread groups found
2019-10-24 16:25:58,226 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
```

seems like taurus disabled all thread groups in its modified_ script when it finds any enabled thread group with test fragment and this is exactly what it did

```
bzt -gui test-frag-and-taurus.yml
```

disable the thread group contains the test fragment solved my issue - although the thread group is disabled, the module controller still able to call the test fragment